# How to reference $(this) when calling a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement the popover component from twitter bootstrap:

```
$('.popover-button').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: $(this).data('content-id')
});

<button class="popover-button" data-content-id="div1">Click 1</button>
<button class="popover-button" data-content-id="div2">Click 2</button>
<button class="popover-button" data-content-id="div3">Click 3</button>

<div class="div1">Hello 1</div>
<div class="div2">Hello 2</div>
<div class="div3">Hello 3</div>
```

But it's not working, it seems I can't use $(this) as I normally would if I was iterating over all the buttons.

So how to do this?

Comment: when you say "implement" do you mean "write your own version of", or just "use" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling a callback, so your existing `$(this)` is irrelevant - it'll be related to whatever value `this` has in the enclosing block.

If your plugin isn't reading the `.data` attribute directly, then you'll need to use a `.each` block to extract each element's value, and then pass those individually to the `.popover` plugin for each individual element:

```
$('.popover-button').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var content = $this.data('content-id');
    $this.popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: content
    });
});
```

Also, your question wording is slightly ambiguous.  If you're just using the standard off-the-shelf Bootstrap plugin then (according to the source) you can in fact just specify a callback function that will return the contents instead of passing a string:

```
content: function() {
    return $(this).data('content-id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the elements and call `popover` on each one.

```
$('.popover-button').each(function(){
    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: $(this).data('content-id')
    });
});
```

Then you can pass each element's info to the method.